# Broken history search after upgrade of oh-my-zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, oh-my-zsh

I did the auto-upgrade of oh-my-zsh a few days ago. Now my filtered history (type a few letters and up arrow) no longer works. I did not realize how dependent I became on it.

---

**EDIT:**

For example, I used to type a few letters of the command and press up arrow to search my history:

```
➜  scratch git:(develop) up   # press ↑ arrow key
```

Prompt changes to:

```
➜  scratch git:(develop) upupdowndownleftrightleftrightbabastartselect # 3 key presses
```

---

I don't know how to what version I was running. Currently:

```
➜  scratch git:(develop) echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.0.2
```

Here are the lines I have in my .zshrc file that I thought were making the incremental search work:

```
# Set bindkeys to start search from last word
bindkey '\e[A' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '\e[B' history-beginning-search-forward
```

Comment: What does `bindkey '\e[A'` show at the prompt?

Comment: Entering that at the command line returns `"^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward`

Comment: Did you upgrade anything other than oh-my-zsh? What happens when you press the Up key now? What is inserted if you press Ctrl+V and then Up? Do the arrow key work as expected in other circumstances?

Comment: @Gilles - Good questions. I did not upgrade anything else to my knowledge (nothing in brew, wget, etc.). 

Pressing the up arrow right now returns the last command.
I am using a Mac, if I press Ctrl V and up arrow I get `^[OA`. If I do `⌘` `V` and paste `gi`, for example, then up arrow I get the last command. 

The arrow keys do work as expected. For example, in VIM they move the cursor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two de facto standard escape sequences for cursor keys; different terminals, or even the same terminal in different modes, can send one or the other. For example, xterm sends `\eOA` for <kbd>Up</kbd> in “application cursor mode” and `\e[A` otherwise. For <kbd>Down</kbd> you can encounter both `\e[B` and `\eOB`, etc.

One solution is to duplicate your bindings: whenever you bind one escape sequence, bind the other escape sequence to the same command.

```
bindkey '\eOA' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '\e[A' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '\eOB' history-beginning-search-forward
bindkey '\e[B' history-beginning-search-forward
```

Another approach is to always bind one escape sequence, and make the other escape sequence inject the other one.

```
bindkey '\e[A' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '\e[B' history-beginning-search-forward
bindkey -s '\eOA' '\e[A'
bindkey -s '\eOB' '\e[B'
```

I don't know why upgrading oh-my-zsh would have affected which escape sequence the shell receives from the terminal. Maybe the new version performs some different terminal initialization that enables application cursor mode.

Comment: Thank you. I replaced my with your first suggested solution, sourced the .zshrc and it worked for me. I did not know there are different modes. For the record I use iTerm2.

Comment: thanks! learned something today. What is "application cursor mode"? also 'bind' works.

Comment: @dashesy It's a terminal mode where some keys send different escape sequences. It's from the era of physical terminal on serial ports. I don't know why it exists, maybe at some point in the past one mode moved the cursor locally on the terminal and the other just sent the keys to applications? It's `bindkey` in zsh, `bind` in bash.