# How to make oh-my-zsh history behavior similar to Bash's?

Tags: zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

I recently switched to oh-my-zsh and I can't get used to the way the arrow up key works. When I enter ssh for example and press up, it only shows me commands starting with ssh while I'd prefer it to show me previous command instead. How could I make it behave the way Bash does, which is what I am already accustomed to?

Note that adding the lines from [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122775/26489) to the end of my zshrc didn't help and it didn't happen after the upgrade, just after switching to oh-my-zsh from bash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broken history search after upgrade of oh-my-zsh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122651/broken-history-search-after-upgrade-of-oh-my-zsh)

Comment: @jasonwryan it doesn't look like a duplicate of that. Adding the lines from the answer to the end of my zshrc didn't help and it didn't happen after the upgrade, just after switching to oh-my-zsh from bash.

Comment: Try removing the directory `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/history-substring-search`.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  Ironically, the other question is the opposite of this one.  In this one, the arrow key recognition and filtered history are working and the questioner wants to know how to **turn them off**; in that question, the problem is that they are **not** working and the questioner wants to know how to repair them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Non-solution

Ironically, the answer in the question that people are proposing as a duplicate …

```
bindkey '\e[A' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '\e[B' history-beginning-search-forward
```

… is *exactly the wrong answer*.  It ensures that your terminal's control sequences for the arrow editing keys are mapped by ZLE to the extension widgets `history-beginning-search-backward` and `history-beginning-search-forward` that are provided by Oh My ZSH's `history-substring-search` plug-in.

That is exactly what you *do not* want.

You're trying to turn this feature off, because you prefer another behaviour; not trying to repair it because it is broken.

## Solution

What you want is those keys to map to the widgets as in vanilla Z Shell, Oh My ZSH being a barrelful of extensions to and customizations of the Z Shell that some (but not all) people like.  Vanilla Z Shell's widgets have roughly the old Bourne Again shell behaviour that you prefer.  (Unlike the Bourne Again shell, though, you if have a multiple-line editing buffer they will move up and down within it before, at the top and bottom edges of the buffer, moving up and down the history.)

Those widgets would be:

```
bindkey "$terminfo[kcuu1]" up-line-or-history
bindkey "$terminfo[kcud1]" down-line-or-history
```

Note how one works to *not hardwire one specific terminal type* into one's scripts.  One could use `"$termcap[ku]"` and `"$termcap[kd]"`, alternatively.  The Z Shell, presuming that you have the appropriate modules loaded, maintains a map for both.  Generally the world prefers terminfo if it has it nowadays, though.  To be strictly bulletproof, in something that you use with heterogeneous systems or give to other people, you'll need a `test -n` in there — just as you'll find the Oh My ZSH extensions doing in fact.

```
test -n "$terminfo[kcuu1]" && bindkey "$terminfo[kcuu1]" up-line-or-history
test -n "$terminfo[kcud1]" && bindkey "$terminfo[kcud1]" down-line-or-history
```

(In extremis, to cope with some unlikely possibilities, you'll need some `"${terminfo[x]-${termcap[y]}}"` variable expansion.  The Oh My ZSH extensions do not bother with that latter, and in practice you can likewise largely get away without it.  In practice, almost everyone has the termcap and terminfo modules loaded, and all that you have to worry about is whether the record for your current terminal type actually defines the relevant control sequences, which is what the `test -n` is for.)

A more exact approximation of the Bourne Again shell behaviour would be

```
bindkey "$terminfo[kcuu1]" up-history
bindkey "$terminfo[kcud1]" down-history
```

That's not the vanilla Z Shell default, and after editing your first multiple-line command line you might decide that the default is what you prefer.  ☺