# Run the same command

Tags: shell, zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

I constantly need to close and re-open programs. To do this I press Control+C > Up Arrow > Enter. However, I have more than one program and need to run different commands for these programs. If I run another command in a new terminal the history changes for the original terminal and the up arrow is no longer the last command. I'm forever accidentally running random commands in the terminal.

I have tried Control+R to search history and `!!` but I do this too frequently and they are too slow.

The ideal situation would be that history for a terminal did not change once the terminal was opened. Even better if that can be done only for arrow keys.

The closest I have gotten is a delay on updating the history.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at terminal multiplexers (tmux, GNU Screen) so that you can dedicate a terminal to this program you launch/stop/restart repeatedly. Run your other commands in other terminal windows to keep your history clean.

Comment: Could you just make yourself some 1-character aliases? `alias 1='my program with some arguments'`

Comment: Thanks for all the great feedback. @KamilMaciorowski I thought I tried this in bash however it appears I am mistaken. I would consider these all viable answers. This is going to save me so much time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a comment that was deleted that explained that Bash did not exhibit the same behavior. That great comment helped me find [How to make oh-my-zsh history behavior similar to Bash's?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324623/how-to-make-oh-my-zsh-history-behavior-similar-to-bashs).

I updated ~/.profile with:

```
bindkey "$terminfo[kcuu1]" up-line-or-history
bindkey "$terminfo[kcud1]" down-line-or-history
```

Which has solved the problem.

Comment: Can you accept your answer, please, so your question doesn't stay open?